# UITableViewRowAnimation with visible imperfections

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have created a UITableView programmatically with 3 cells in the section at index 0. Now when I flip the UISwitch in the cell at index 0 in that section it animates the insertion of a third cell.

Unfortunately I get those weird lines at the end of a UITableViewRowAnimation as you can see in the picture below. The same happens when the deletion of the cell is animated.

http://cl.ly/0l120K091b3s0h3J1l3m

Can someone tell me how to fix this? It looks really ugly. Here the code that gets executed when the UISwitch is on:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSArray *rowAtIndex2inSectionAtIndex0 = 
        [NSArray arrayWithObject:
        [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]];

if ([defaults boolForKey:@"one"] == 1 && 
    [defaults boolForKey:@"two"] == 1 && 
    numberOfRowsInSection0 == 2) 
{
    numberOfRowsInSection0++;

    [self.tableView 
    insertRowsAtIndexPaths:rowAtIndex2inSectionAtIndex0 
    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the row heights you are returning and make sure they are whole numbers and not fractions.

Comment: Do you mean the cell row heights? I didn't set custom heights for the cells.

Comment: How are you specifying the tableview row heights if not through your tableviewdelegate?

Comment: Since I didn't set custom heights the table view will have chosen default values I think. I wanted my table view to look exactly like Apple's e.g. the Settings.app. The only thing I specified are footer and header heights.

Comment: Maybe try explicitly setting the row heights in your tableview delegate using: `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: I added this in two different projects and the same keeps happening :( :     

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44.0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I've found the arbitrary line mid transition you mention can be removed with the following: -

```
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```